# Change value of static field in a static method

Tags: java, static

I have a `SampleClass` with static field `a` and `b` and a static method `init`. To re-create `SampleClass` with new value for `a` and `b`, I use below syntax:

```
public class SampleClass{

    private static int b;
    private static int a;
    
    public static void init(int a, int b) {
        SampleClass.a = a; //line 7
        SampleClass.b = b; //line 8
    }
}
```

I actually feel awkward about line 7 and line 8. Is this acceptable or there are more correct ways to do this?

Comment: Could you explain why you feel awkward about them?

Comment: I feel awkward calling the SampleClass within the SampleClass. It does what I need to do but I am not sure if there is an effect using this convention

Comment: I'm not sure how to address you confusion because it's unclear but I can tell you that there's nothing inacceptable with the lines.

Comment: Thanks @akuzminykh! You're assurance is helpful enough :)

Comment: SampleClass.a = a; is the recommended way if the variable name conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is **not** wrong.

For `static` attributes, you either use the syntax you have provided in your question, either you assign different names for your parameters (for code self-explanatory reasons).
For instance:

```
public static void init(int newA, int newB) {
    SampleClass.a = newA;
    SampleClass.b = newB;
}
```

Comment: It won't work because it will throw `Cannot use this in a static context`

Comment: I think you're basically ignoring the question and just dump information about setters.

Comment: You're right, I did a tremendous mistake. I didn't ignore his answer, but I wanted to clarify some aspects.

Comment: @DavidBuzatu Okay, well done. But now don't just edit your answer with an excuse and don't keep the wrong part. Just give it a small rework so it answers the OP's question without any noisy text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's acceptable. In fact if you generate a `Setter` method for a static field, the assign way will also be `SampleClass.a = a`.